# Why there is limit in number of files we can open at a time,or number of network connection we can open at a time

Tags: file-io, operating-system

Why there is limit in number of files we can open at a time,or number of network connection we can open at a time? As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux  accepted answer is,it is because of main memory there is limit in opening files.Answer does not seems perfect to me,because

1.Memory is also involved on execution of program but there is no any limit in number of user process we can run at a time.

2.if we initiate command to open 1000 files at a time,in main memory there will be just 10000 instruction to read data from some particulate location of disc.memory will be involved when reading of file will be started.so opening number of file should not be problem, size of a file can be.

also,it is always said if after opening a file if you don't close file,resource will be wasted.which resource are they talking about?

Comment: The OS has to do some bookkeeping when a file, or in general a resource, is opened. This takes space in the main memory (albeit small) and such space is freed only when the resource is closed. This is true for processes too, see [Fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). The bookkeeping is necessary for optimisations, for keeping multiple states of a file, for security reasons, for enforcing sharing policies and it gives rise to the "open/use/close" paradigm that is very idiomatic; it allows, in a very simple example, to "wake" the hardware in "open" and put it to sleep in "close"

Comment: to expand on that a little, if there were no such thing as file descriptors, `read()` would take a filename as a string, and would need a file position (since it couldn't remember a position between `read()` calls; remember we're trying to imagine a system where *no* kernel memory is spent on open-file state).  So every `read()` would have to redo all the permission checks (including for `x` permission on all the parent directories in the path).